# How to make a font in Android as big as the device width?

Tags: android

I need to do the following and I dont know how:
I want to write a text like "12" on the screen which is in portrait mode.

The challange is, that I want to make the font size as big as 90% of the device screen width.

Is this possible? the whole text should be 90% of the device width. When I add a character like "123" is should scale down.

Comment: https://github.com/danclarke/AutoResizeTextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various implementations of a `TextView` that resizes the text to fit the available space, such as [this one](https://github.com/danclarke/AutoResizeTextView). If you set up the `TextView` to be the right physical size, the auto-sizing feature will handle scaling the text accordingly.

Comment: this is a C# implementation and not android (java)